# range autoextend disabled by "set link y"

Tags: gnuplot

As soon as I use `set link y2` the autoextend (scale to the next full tics) of the y axis is disabled.

I want to have tics with labels on both sides of the y axis. In 5.2 I just `set y2tics` and that's it. In 5.4 it doesn't work for me. After googling I understood that this may or may not work, is not "clean". The "clean" way would be to `set link y2` so that both sides are bound together. Nice, and works.

But this breaks autoextend, so my plots are drawn like in fit mode, and stick to the top and bottom borders. While this is not very important, the graphs still "look better" when autoextend is active. I tried to explicitly set it to on, to no available.

A very simple example is to draw `sin(x)*1.1`. With autoextend, y scale will go till -1.5/+1.5 and without, it is clamped to -1.1/1.1

```
set link y2
plot sin(x)*1.1
```

Did I miss something? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain whether this is a bug or not, but one way around the problem is to specify that you want blank space above and/or below the y extent of the plot:

```
set link y2
set offset 0,0,.1,.1
plot sin(x)*1.1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, and this one is a good workaround for me. It's even better when by chance your data can reach exactly one of the ticks and thus still have no margin with autoexpand.
Also, one can specify an offset in percent of the whole graph, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same behaviour as the one you describe.

In order to get `y2` tics without setting `link y2`, you could use

```
set y2range [GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]
```

before replotting or after a `stats` command that'll determine `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to plot the function twice (well, not so nice), once related to the axes x1 and y1 and the second time ("invisible" with `lt -2`) related to the axes x1 and y2. Check `help axes`. This will work in this simple example, but might get tedious in more complex plots.

**Code:**

```
### workaround for missing autoextend with linked axis
reset session

f(x) = sin(x)*1.1

set y2tics

plot f(x) axis x1y1 lc "red", \
     f(x) axis x1y2 lt -2 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]